# Como puedo hacer clik sobre un boton con SELENIUM | web scraping

Tags: python, web, scraping

espero me puedan ayudar. Estoy haciendo una practica web scraping con SELENIUM-PYTHON, soy novato en el lenguaje y web scraping. Tengo problemas al querer accionar el CLIC sobre un botón, tengo la sospecha de que SELENIUM no logra detectar el botón pero no estoy seguro. Les comparto fragmentos del código.

```
#Aquí inicializo selenium#
class DataExtraction:
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)


#Clase que hace el envió de mensajes 
def send_messages(self, message):
        for contact_info in self.contact_info_list:
            if contact_info.list_link:
                # Comprueba si el contacto tiene un enlace
                # Abre el perfil del contacto
                self.driver.get(contact_info.list_link)
                # Espera a que el botón "Enviar mensaje" esté presente y visible
                try:
                    #Aquí es donde esta el problema para hacer clic sobre el botón
                    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
                        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "artdeco-button artdeco-button--2")))
                    message_button = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
                        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "artdeco-button artdeco-button--2")))
                    message_button.click()



#este es el código HTML de la pagina en cuestión
<button aria-label="Enviar mensaje a PEPETOÑO" id="ember3800" class="artdeco-button artdeco-button--2 artdeco-button--primary ember-view pvs-profile-actions__action">  <li-icon aria-hidden="true" type="send-privately" class="artdeco-button__icon" size="small"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16" data-supported-dps="16x16" fill="currentColor" class="mercado-match" width="16" height="16" focusable="false">
      <path d="M14 2L0 6.67l5 2.64 5.67-3.98L6.7 11l2.63 5L14 2z"></path>
    </svg></li-icon>

<span class="artdeco-button__text">
    Enviar mensaje
</span></button>
```

Comment: Ten en cuenta que a la selección por nombre de clase se le pasa el nombre de una sola clase. Si necesitas buscar por las dos clases tendrás que hacer selección por XPATH o CSS.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, lo que trato de hacer es esperar a que este presente el boton.                                                           
 WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
                        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "artdeco-button artdeco-button--2")))  Una ves que el boton este presente lo que hice fue ubicarlo y dar click sobre el:  message_button = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
                        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "artdeco-button artdeco-button--2")))
message_button.click()

Comment: ya habia utilizado xpath y css. Tambien queria utilizar el id pero cambia cada vez que se ingresa la pagina web

Comment: Si siempre aparece en la misma posición dentro del DOM, no debería ser problema localizarlo con un selector CSS o XPATH. O hacer una selección amplia (eg: todos los botones de una clase) e ir mirando uno a uno cuál es el que te puede interesar.

Comment: Lo que he notado es que la etiqueta <button> no tiene el atributo type="submit" y tiene algun bloqueador. Esto es en la pagina linkedin, es el boton Enviar mensaje que está dentro del perfil de un contacto.